# Use ncdu without installing anything on a remote machine

Tags: ssh, disk-usage, ncdu

I want to use `ncdu` to scan directories on a remote machine and see how many files are in which directory, how big they are, etc. The remote machine is either slow or has a lot of files or both - `find /` takes a very long time (1h+). This machine is a production server and I would like to avoid installing any packages on it.

Is there a way to open an SSH connection, and make the `ncdu` running on my local machine scan the files through the SSH connection?

It looks like there is an `ncdu -o-` command to export the scan, but that requires `ncdu` to be installed on the machine. I could also just put the `ncdu` binary on the machine without installing, and then run that, but ideally I would like to avoid that as well.

Comment: Depending on your privilege level you could use `sshfs` to mount the remote direcotry in question ... I wouldn't expect this to be any faster than a `find`  executed locally on the server, though.